# Spring REST equivalent of ContainerRequestContext

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jersey-2.0

What is a Spring equivalent of Jersey's ContainerRequestContext?
I am trying to get the SecurityContext (.getSecurityContext()) like we can from a ContainerRequestContext.

Does spring-mvc have something similar?

Answer (score 0):

you can get/load in using annotations most things you would use ContainerRequestContext. For example cookies

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String hello(@CookieValue("font-style") String fontStyle) {
// ...
}
```

For the SecurityContext, check out the following

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/get-current-logged-in-username-in-spring-security/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `interface HttpServletRequest`